# HangMan Error output

Tags: java

i seem to have a problem which i cant fix, when a user enters the complete word for my program it displays each time it searches a char instead of just displaying the whole word saying that they had guessed it correctly. How would i get it to just display the word only and not show each time it search's a char when the user enters the whole word? thanks for future replys

```
package assignment1Q2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class HangmanClassExample {

static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
static int play, size, size2;
static String word;
static String[] ARRAY = new String[0];


public static void main(String[] args) {

    setUpGame();
}

public static void setUpGame() {
    System.err.printf("Welcome to hangman.\n");

    try {

        Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File("H:\\Varsity work\\Java Programming\\Programs\\HangMan\\src\\hangman\\HangMan.txt"));
        String line;
        while (scFile.hasNext()) {
            line = scFile.nextLine();
            Scanner scLine = new Scanner(line);
            size++;
        }
        ARRAY = new String[size];
        Scanner scFile1 = new Scanner(new File("H:\\Varsity work\\Java Programming\\Programs\\HangMan\\src\\hangman\\HangMan.txt"));
        while (scFile1.hasNext()) {
            String word;
            line = scFile1.nextLine();
            Scanner scLine = new Scanner(line);
            word = scLine.next();
            ARRAY[size2] = word;
            size2++;
            calculateGuess();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public static void calculateGuess() {

    try {
        do {

            int random = (int) (Math.random() * ARRAY.length);
            String randomWord = ARRAY[random];
            String word = randomWord;
            char[] ranWord = randomWord.toCharArray();
            char[] dash = word.toCharArray();

            int LEFT = 6;
            for (int i = 0; i < dash.length; i++) {
                dash[i] = '-';
                System.out.print(dash[i]);
            }
      for (int A = 1; A <= dash.length;) {
            System.out.print("\nGuess a Letter:");
            String userletters = keyboard.next();;

            for (int i = 0; i < userletters.length(); i++) {
                char userLetter = userletters.charAt(i);
                String T = Character.toString(userLetter);
                for (int B = 0; B < ranWord.length; B++) {

                    if (userLetter == dash[B]) {
                        System.out.println("this '" + userLetter + "' letter already exist");
                        B++;
                        if (userLetter == dash[B-1]) {
                            break;
                        }


                    } else if (userLetter == ranWord[B]) {
                        dash[B] = userLetter;
                        A--;
                    }
                }
                if (!(new String(ranWord).contains(T))) {
                    LEFT--;
                    System.out.println("You did not guess a correct letter, you have " + LEFT + " OF "
                            + dash.length + " trys left to guess correctly");
                }

                System.out.println(dash);
            }
            if ((new String(word)).equals(new String(dash))) {
                System.out.println("\nYou have guessed the word correctly!");
                break;

            }

        }

            System.out.println("Play agian? (y/n)");
            String name = keyboard.next();

            if (name.equals("y")) {
                play = 0;

            } else {
                play = 1;
                return;
            }
        } while (play == 0);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
}
```

}

OUTPUT:

```
Welcome to hangman.



--------

Guess a Letter:c

c-------

Guess a Letter:c

this 'c' letter already exist

c-------

Guess a Letter:computer

this 'c' letter already exist

c-------

co------

com-----

comp----

compu---

comput--

compute-

computer

You have guessed the word correctly!

Play agian? (y/n)

n
```

Comment: You should read about [variable naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: When you get an answer from the player why dont you just compare the whole word with the given one and if they do not match check for the letters..

Comment: @burhancerit How would i do that

Comment: @burhancerit Thank you i managed to fix the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having two for loops and checking each character, you can use `startsWith` to check for character that user has entered. For e.g. if user enters, `comp` , you can simply check `originalString.startsWith(comp)` - if true, just print comp and remove the first 4 characters from originalString.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the *if* out of your *for* loop like this

```
        if ((new String(word)).equals(new String(dash))) {
            System.out.println("\nYou have guessed the word correctly!");
            // break; not needed anymore as we're out of the loop

        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < userletters.length(); i++) {
            char userLetter = userletters.charAt(i);
            String T = Character.toString(userLetter);
            for (int B = 0; B < ranWord.length; B++) {

                if (userLetter == dash[B]) {
                    System.out.println("this '" + userLetter + "' letter already exist");
                    B++;
                    if (userLetter == dash[B-1]) {
                        break;
                    }


                } else if (userLetter == ranWord[B]) {
                    dash[B] = userLetter;
                    A--;
                }
            }
            if (!(new String(ranWord).contains(T))) {
                LEFT--;
                System.out.println("You did not guess a correct letter, you have " + LEFT + " OF "
                        + dash.length + " trys left to guess correctly");
            }

            System.out.println(dash);
        }
    }
```

}

But in my opinion, in that kind of game, the user should only be able to input one character and not the whole word.